# Passing parameter to FTP macro

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ftp

I have developed a bash script that contains an `FTP` invocation.

Because the actions i do are based on a routine i have added a `macro` inside the `.netrc`
file in my home directory.

This is a small example of my macro

```
macdef getFile
        lcd ../../test/
        get test1.txt
        quit
```

In this macro i am changing local directory and i place the file that i want.

What i want to parameterize is the name of the file.Because i am making always the same actions but with different name of that file.

Is there any possible way to pass an argument to the Macro when is called inside the ftp connection ?

something like ?

```
ftp>$ getFile anotherTestFile.txt
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to do the same thing. Normally I'd install ncftp or something more helpful but I couldn't, so what I had to do was make a shell script to do it:

1) set up your .netrc correctly to handle login, directory change, etc. Don't have the macro quit or anything like that, just have it get to where you want the file to go and then the macro stops. Like what you did but I just don't the "quit" line.

2) make a shell script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
  echo "put $1" > ftpCmdTemp
  ftp your.hostname.here < ftpCmdTemp
  rm ftpCmdTemp
else
  echo "need a filename"
fi
```

3) save this to somewhere in your path, and make it executable. I called it "pushLog", so in my case, "chmod +x pushLog"

4) now I can just run
`pushLog someLogFile.txt`
and it will transfer whatever I give it (make sure `pushLog` is in your path and all that.)